# Installing the Java Card Development Kit in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javacard

JCDK downloaded, installed. In the IDEA project itself, I connected JDK 8, and added files for the Java Card as a library. But the Idea does not know everything about Applets and stuff from the Java Card api. how to be?

Comment: Make sure the jars are present in the module dependencies: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies.